# Wait for Callbacks to complete before returning to the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I have a dynamic case where user will post a array of data which i need to insert into the database in different rows. How do i wait for the calls back to complete before returning success or failure to the user.

I tried using promise but it returns this

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined (node:6216) DeprecationWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
>   rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
>   with a non-zero exit code.

My trails with promises

```
req.targetting.forEach(data => {
      let s = {};
      if (data.value == '' || data.value.length == 0) {
        s = 99;
      } else {
        s = data.status;
      }
      let promises =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        XXX.upsertWithWhere(where clause,data, (err, data) => { // a loopback method
            if (err) {
              return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(data);
          });
      });
      Promise.all(promises).then((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, data);
      });
    });
  };
```

I thought of put promises out side but still the same error with rejection id 3

The signature for the upsert method

```
PersistedModel.upsertWithWhere([where], data, callback)
```

Comment: Promise.all() takes an iterable object I guess you are just passing a single promise. Also from your promise.all() block you are returning a callback() function, where is that function even declared? Its not in the `arguments`.

Comment: @KumarShubham there is some mistake i am not getting that what i want is that get all the promises and return only when the callbacks have completed

Comment: That unhandled rejection comes because you are passing a promise instead of an iterable object to the Promise.all() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this should be fine(I didnt test this code)

```
let promises = [];
req.targetting.forEach(data => {
let s = {};
if (data.value == '' || data.value.length == 0) {
  s = 99;
} else {
  s = data.status;
}
let promise =  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  XXX.upsertWithWhere(whereclause,data, (err, data) => { // a loopback 
  //method
  if (err) {
    return reject(err);
  }
    return resolve(data);
  });
});
promises.push(promise);
});
Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
  return data;
})
.catch((err) => {
  return err;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap your iteration in another method. Build a list of promises and then wait for it to resolve. Eg below

```
function orgMethod(){
            let promises =[];
            req.targetting.forEach(data => {
                  let s = {};
                  if (data.value == '' || data.value.length == 0) {
                    s = 99;
                  } else {
                    s = data.status;
                  }
                  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    XXX.upsertWithWhere(where clause,data, (err, data) => { // a loopback method
                        if (err) {
                          return reject(err);
                        }
                        return resolve(data);
                      });
                  }));

                });
              };
     Promise.all(promises).then((err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                      return callback(err);
                    }
                    callback(null, data);
                  });
        }
```